# JQuery.Ajax in Samsung Smart TV not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, eclipse

I used JQuery.Ajax to try to communicate with my webservice

Here is how the code looks like:

```
Main.onLoad = function() {
    // Enable key event processing
    this.enableKeys();
    widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent();
    //$("#h2Test").html("Change On Text");

        $.ajax({
                    url : 'http://---.--.---.--:-----/_layouts/-----/------.asmx?op=retrieveEvents',
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType : 'json',
                    contentType : 'application/json',
                    data : {
                        url : "someURL"
                    },
                    success : function(response) {
                        $("#h2Test").html("SUCCESS");
                    },
                    failure : function(response) {
                        $("#h2Test").html("FAIL");
                    }
        });
};
```

When i run the codes, Change On Text is displayed instead of SUCCESS or FAIL, why doesn't the code reaches either success or error

Comment: What is json.type? One probably reason could be a syntax error, your ajax not even got executed. Check your console.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ you should replace your

```
failure: function(response) {
```

with

```
error: function(response) {
```

It probably should reach the error function then.

Comment: also remove the "contentType" thing. Are you sure your server expecting request "contentType" as "application/json"? The common web apis just use default POST content type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

In mobile and tv apps you should take care about "same domain policy" by using: dataType: "jsonp" and jsonpCallback (also declaring the latter). Take a look:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

and

[Callback function for JSONP with JQuery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613815/callback-function-for-jsonp-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: what is jsonp? and what does it do?

Comment: The browsers has a security concept: "same domain policy", it restrict your scripts to the same domain so your tv or mobile app will have that restriction because your webservice domain www.somedomain.com and your app domain (local) is different. jsonp is a technique that solve this and allow you to make cross-domain requests . See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096867/same-domain-policy-jquery

Comment: Very well explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about